# PHP Extra 1 empty row when using mysql_data_seek

Tags: php, mysql

I try to get a result from the same MySQL more than once, so I am using mysql_data_seek but the result always add one empty row at the first data

Here is my **code** :

```
<?php mysql_data_seek($Recordset1,0);?>
            data: [

            <?php do { ?>

      <?php echo $row_Recordset1['kbo1'].","; ?>
      <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
            ]
```

**THERE IS ONE EMPTY ROW, IN THE BEGINNING, CHECK THE SCREENSHOT:**

[image]

i dont know if i put the mysql_data_seek at the right place or there is another way to using mysql_data_seek

Comment: `WARNING! This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're outputting a value before you read from the table. Try changing to a `while` loop instead:

```
<?php mysql_data_seek($Recordset1,0);?>
        data: [
<?php while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)) {
           echo $row_Recordset1['kbo1'].","; ?>
      } ?>
        ]
```